# Can´t install phpMyAdmin

Tags: software-sources, phpmyadmin

I tried to install [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) by running:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

but I got the error message that phpMyAdmin cannot be found. I found the notice to activate the universe repository in my Software Sources, but I still got the same error message. How can I install phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Did you `sudo apt-get update` afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

In order to install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu, you need to have Apache2 , MySQL and PHP  installed and configured properly.

After installing apache2, MySQL and PHP, you can install and configure phpmyadmin.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```